# AutoMapper: setup member name matching convention

Tags: c#, automapper

I tried setting up a member name mapping convention so that the source members ending with a "Id" are mapped to destination members without Id. For example

UserId -> User

How does one do this? I tried using SourceMemberNameTransformer without success. Also tried using RecognizePostfixes().

```
    this.SourceMemberNameTransformer = s =>
                                      {     
                                          return s.Replace("Id", string.Empty);
                                      };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without success?"  Post a full working example, the expected behaviour, and the actual behaviour, and you may be more likely to receive a good answer.

Comment: I agree.  I'd love to have more context on this question because I have the same issue.

Comment: Warning: it seems the property "SourceMemberNameTransformer" has been removed in after version 2.1.1 of Automapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now this does not seem to work when setting it in the `Profile`. Neither `SourceMemberNameTransformer` or `RecognizePostfix` work in `Profile`. However is specified in Automapper global configuration it works fine.

Comment: 4 years later, it still doesn't work. /cc @jimmy-bogard

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "RecognizePostfixes" method:

```
this.RecognizePostfixes("Id");
```

The built-in transformer is this, just for future reference:

```
s => Regex.Replace(s, "(?:^Get)?(.*)", "$1");
```

Comment: This doesn't work inside a [`Profile`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration).

Comment: Can you open a GitHub issue then?

Answer (score 0):

This should to work:

> ```
> this.SourceMemberNameTransformer = s =>
>           {
>               if (s.EndsWith("Id"))
>                   return s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);               
>               return s;
>           };
> ```

You also can try achieve that with `DestinationMemberNamingConvention` and regex.

Comment: This is same as what I have ?

Comment: Yes. but yours risking any string that contain 'id', like Bid. ans EndsWith by default is case secretive so it is more safe.

Comment: String.Replace is case sensitive as well - *This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) search to find oldValue*. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx